# Unable to copy large video files from iOS device to Windows XP machine

Tags: windows-xp, usb, iphone, ipod, ios

Connecting my iOS5 iPhone 3GS to a Windows XP SP3 machine brings up the "Microsoft Scanner and Camera Wizard," which fails to copy large (>1 GB) videos with the error:

> The current picture could not be copied. To copy this picture, click "Try Again." To stop copying, click "Cancel."

Clicking "Try Again" brings up the same error (either immediately, or after a pause).  Clicking cancel brings up another screen with a "detailed error information" link that produces:

> The following problem occurred while copying pictures:
> Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

(There *is* enough space on the drive to store the video.)

Trying to copy the file via Windows Explorer instead of the wizard results in a copy dialog that shows no progress, and finishes with a 0 byte file after a minute or so.

Microsoft appears to know about this problem, as it's [in their Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814390) (symptoms 2 & 3, not 1 which there was a patch for).  Their solution is to set the device to "USB Mass Storage Class" instead of "Picture Transfer Protocol", but I don't know of a way to do this on an iPhone.  Does anyone else?

I've tried iExplorer (formerly iPhone Explorer), to no avial (it doesn't even see my phone).

## Is there any way for me to get large video files from my phone to my computer?

**Update:**
To address concerns that this is related to FAT file size limits, the XP partition is NTFS and I see the behavior with a 1.69 GB (1,694,770,716 bytes) file (though it happens with other large files too).  There's also an intermediate size where the wizard will fail, but copying via Explorer works.  Above some size though, now way to get them transferred that I've found.

Comment: What format is the partition where the destination folder resides (fat or NTFS) - you can check in Disk Manager?

Comment: What is the exact size of one of these video files? It would help to know.

Comment: How much space is left on the drive?

Comment: @wizlog I'm seeing this on multiple machines with multiple files.  I get the erroneous behavior with 1.69 GB file mentioned above on a machine with 3.67 GB free, but I also see it for a 1.56 GB file on another machine with 105 GB free.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Macroplant's [Phone Disk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/) which works fine, but it pains me to have to buy software to get videos I've taken from my phone to my computer.  Better solutions are still more than welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Install iTunes. Sync phone using iTunes, including videos. Report back if there are further issues.

UPDATE:

Downvoting because you do not find the solution palatable is not good manners. Please leave downvotes for those situations where the answer is offensive or completely and totally unhelpful or absolutely wrong.

Your iPhone was made to do what Steve Jobs wanted you to do with it, and that includes limiting all transfers to and from the device to iTunes. If you wanted freedom, you should have bought an Android device.

That said, there are plenty of free apps that will let you get around this limitation.

Dropbox is probably the easiest, though, using it for "large videos" will probably mean you're at the mercy of your internet connection. Any file transfer or file browser app should allow you to connect to file shares on your home/desktop computer so long as your home network firewall is configured properly. I use the File Browser app, which I don't think is free, but which works very, very well. These apps allow direct file transfer over a network. You're limited to network speed, which is usually a lot less than USB/iTunes speed, but you get the file with a "normal" name in the location you want it.

UPDATE 2:

It wasn't a bad answer, it was an inconvenient answer. It was the first answer that actually got the files where you wanted them. Though I agree that UUID-named files can, in many cases, be worse than no file at all, when looked at from a frustration level standpoint.

I'm still at a little loss as to your antagonism though. If the solution isn't elegant enough simply say so. For instance "Hey, I found the files, it works, but the files are all UUID-named, which doesn't do me much good. So are there ways to get this to work so that I'll see a "normal" file name in a "normal" location on my HDD?" That communicates the same thing to me and does it in a way that makes me want to try harder for you.

Carrots are best when the situation is voluntary. For instance, I don't have to answer your question, but there are things you can do that make it more valuable for me to answer it, like being nice and getting me emotionally invested in finding the solution. Using a stick only works when there isn't much choice. But there is nothing you could do to me here that could get you enough leverage over me to force me to answer your question. -2 points? That's less than 2 hundredths of one percentage of my total points right now. You just can't make me *want* to help you by downvoting, and my points aside, I have a lot of experience and I like to share it. Don't make me want to share with everybody except you.

Comment: I can do that (though it would be nice to be able to get them without having to sync), but where are the videos afterwards?  iTunes doesn't have a "Photos" area, and the videos aren't showing up under "Movies".

Comment: Okay, I found where it put them: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\<random UUID>\  However, all the files are also named via UUID, even lacking extensions.  In this case I can guess the file I'm interested in based on the size, but it's not a workable solution if I need to do this with any regularity (which I will).

Comment: You're that bothered over losing two rep for a bad answer?  As you've added some other possible solutions, I'm happy to rescind the downvote and try them out.  Thanks for the help.